# Pygame spritecollide error

Tags: python, pygame

I have a few questions about pygame. I am completely new to python/pygame and curious if for one, I am doing this properly, or if I am writing this sloppy.

And for my other question, when I use spritecollide, object seems to still be there even after the image disappears. Let me share the code

```
import pygame, time, random, sys, player, creep, weapon
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

#Variables for the game
width  = 700
height = 500
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Creep')

#Create Characters of the game
player1 = player.Player()
player1.rect.x = 0
player1.rect.y = 0

comp = creep.Creep()
comp.rect.x = random.randrange(width)
comp.rect.y = random.randrange(height)


bullet = weapon.Weapon()
bullet.rect.x = -1
bullet.rect.y = -1

#Make Character Groups
good = pygame.sprite.Group(player1)
bad = pygame.sprite.Group(comp)
weap = pygame.sprite.Group(bullet)


while True:
clock.tick(60)
screen.fill((0,0,0))

#set up for game to get input
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
        sys.exit()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_c:
        bullet.rect.x = player1.rect.x + 25
        bullet.rect.y = player1.rect.y

#main controls
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[K_RIGHT]:
    player1.rect.x = player1.moveRight(player1.rect.x)
if key[K_LEFT]:
    player1.rect.x = player1.moveLeft(player1.rect.x)
if key[K_DOWN]:
    player1.rect.y = player1.moveDown(player1.rect.y)
if key[K_UP]: 
    player1.rect.y = player1.moveUp(player1.rect.y)

if bullet.rect.x > -1:
    weap.draw(screen)
    bullet.rect.x = bullet.rect.x +5


pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, bad, True)
pygame.sprite.spritecollide(comp, good, True)

#game functions
good.draw(screen)
bad.draw(screen)

pygame.display.flip()
```

So I have an image of a gun (player1, 'good' group), an image for the computer (comp, 'bad' group), and an image for a "bullet" when LCTRL is hit (bullet, 'weap' group).. when the bullet hits the image from the bad group, it disappears, which is what I want. But then when I move the player1 image in that direction, it will disappear as if the 'bad group' was still there. I hope this makes sense.

An example code of the classes I am calling on look like this:

```
import pygame

class Creep(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load('creep.jpg')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Any idea? and if there is a better way of going at this please let me know, I only started learning a week ago, and don't know if I am going in the proper direction, or not. Thanks!

Comment: could you add your collision code? what happens when the bullet collides?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure what some of your variables were. Note: If you put a sprite in multiple groups, then **kill** it, it **will kill it in all groups automatically**.

I started cleaning up the code.

```
#import time, sys, # not longer required 

import player, creep, weapon
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

#Variables for the game
width  = 700
height = 500
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Creep')

#Create Characters of the game
player1 = player.Player()
player1.rect.x = 0
player1.rect.y = 0

comp = creep.Creep()
comp.rect.topleft = random.randrange(width), random.randrange(height)

bullet = pygame.sprite.Sprite()# weapon.Weapon()
bullet.rect.topleft = (-1, -1)

#Make Character Groups
good = pygame.sprite.Group(player1)
bad = pygame.sprite.Group(comp)
weap = pygame.sprite.Group(bullet)

done = False

while not done:
    clock.tick(60)

    #set up for game to get input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: done = True
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE: done = True

            elif event.key == K_c:
                bullet.rect.x = player1.rect.x + 25
                bullet.rect.y = player1.rect.y

    #main controls
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[K_RIGHT]:
        player.rect.x += 10
    if key[K_LEFT]:
        player1.rect.x -= 10
    if key[K_DOWN]:
        player.rect.y += 10
    if key[K_UP]: 
        player.rect.y -= 10    

    # movement, collisions
    pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, bad, True)
    pygame.sprite.spritecollide(comp, good, True)

    # not sure what this was for? If you meant 'onscreen' or?
    # You can kill it if it goes offscreen. Otherwise draw works if offscreen.
    if bullet.rect.x > -1:
        bullet.rect.x += 5

    screen.fill(Color("black"))
    weap.draw(screen)

    #game functions
    good.draw(screen)
    bad.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thanks @monkey, the bullet.rect.x > -1 is so when you hit c on the keyboard, the 'bullet' would shoot from the image, and continue to go forward. My issue was once the 'bullet' collided with the any img in the 'comp' group, the item would disappear, as I wanted but the player would still collide with it has if it was still there.
Best example I can give is like space invaders. You have the ability to shoot the ghosts, but the ghost got you you would die. on mine, if i was to shoot the ghost, it would die but if i directed my player in that direction, the area i killed the ghost, would kill me

Comment: Oh you mean you want bullets to collide + kill ghosts. and ghosts collide to kill player?

Comment: yes, but when the bullets collide with the ghosts, the ghost disappears but the player moves to where the ship would have been, the player dies as if the ghost was still there, that is the main issue I am having.. and thanks for the cleaner code